# How can I make sure trimming in ffmpeg with -c:v copy is accurate

Tags: ffmpeg

I looked at many things online and I understand it's better to re-encode if you want precision.

But for instance, I have the following command:

```
-ss 00:00:09 -i "input.mp4" -c:v copy -c:a copy -vframes 600 "output.mp4
```

Where 600 is calculated using the video's FPS and duration, in this case 10 seconds from an 60FPS video. Can I expect to get something accurate with this all the time? I tested many variants but this seems to be doing ok for the couple videos I tested for.. And if not, can I really ever get complete ACCURACY with copying, or must I stick to H264 for instance?

Answer (score 0):

> Question: can I really ever get complete ACCURACY with copying

No. Copying requires you cut on key frames.